# How can I get residuals output in a variable or to act like a data frame in R?

Tags: least-squares, residuals, r

I have an object:

```
noise.lm
```

it's just a simple linear model with an X and Y.

when I type in

```
resid(noise.lm)
```

it produces the residuals like this:

```
         1           2           3           4           5           6 
-0.40501681 -1.16960373 -0.66636219 -0.41798296  1.37942381  0.84336242
```

I would like to access the residual values without the observation numbers, maybe by making a data frame like this

```
   residual
1  -0.40501681
2  -1.16960373
3  -0.66636219
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

Or is there an easier way to store just the residual value in a variable like:

```
residual_variable

-0.40501681, -1.16960373, -0.66636219, -0.41798296,  1.37942381,  0.84336242
```

An example of what I would like to do would be something like testing for autocorrelation

```
plot(length(residual_variable),residual_variable)
```

or when trying to check normality with a histogram...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why `residual_variable <- resid(noise.lm)` is not suitable for you? If observation numbers really bug you, just remove them, `names(residual_variable)<- NULL`. Or convert to data.frame: `data.frame(residual=resid(noise.lm))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
MyData$Resids <- residuals(noise.lm)
```

where `MyData` is your data used to create `noise.lm`?